# Visually representing a denormalized dataset in SQL reporting services

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, reporting

I'm trying to take a denormalized data set and turn it into a report containing a horizontal table layout of data grouped and subgrouped.  I realize there are probably better ways to contain the data and better ways to visualize this data, but this is what I have to work with.

Here is the scenario...  I have the following CustomerOrderDataTable:

[image]

With the following data:

[image]

And I'm trying to get it to look like:

[image]

The one final requirement on this is to allow for jagged data groups, butting up against each other vertically like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first table you can do something like this.

Set a matrix with one column group, grouped on `CustomerId`:

[image]

There are only two textboxes - one has `CustomerName`. Insert a table into the other textbox:

[image]

[image]

This embedded table is grouped on `OrderId`. `OrderDate` is displayed in the group header and `OrderItemName` in the detail row. Since this is embedded in the column group, the table will be repeated for each customer and only display rows in that Scope.

Final result looks like this based on your data:

[image]

Not 100% sure about the stacked grouping, but hopefully this will be of some use.

Comment: Absolutely amazing!  Thank you for the detailed explanation.  Simple, concise, and most importantly it works!